# Nodejs is reloading app.get every 2 minute

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, node.js

I am using node.js for the first time and I have a problem with it because it is refreshing one of the get methods( **app.get('/addToHistory'**) every 2 minutes without any iteraction from my side or browser. Probably the problem is somewhere in my server.js configuration but I cannot found it.

I am trying to build an SPA with AngularJS, NodeJS and MySQL. There will be 3 pages: Home page (with some images), Image page (user can click on image from home page to see details about this image) and History (all images which user saw). There wouldn't be any login functionality. App is recognizing the user by session id, which is saved to the DB.

I am using the routing of angular to navigate between different pages.

Here is the configuration of my server.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var express = require('express');
var app = module.exports = express();
var session = require('express-session');
var MySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);

app.use(cookieParser());

var db_options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    //port: 3306,
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'myDB'
};

var option = {
    host: 'localhost',
    //port: 3306,
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'myDB',
    schema: {
        tableName: 'sessions',
        columnNames: {
            sessions_id: 'sessions_id',
            expires: 'expires',
            data: 'data'
        }
    }
};

var method = db.prototype;

function db() {
    var con = mysql.createPool(db_options);
    this.connection = con;
}

method.getcon = function () {
    return this;
};

module.exports = db;
var connection_object = new db();
var db_connection = connection_object.connection;

app.get('/load', function (req, res) {
    console.log('load');
    db_connection.query("SELECT * from sessions", function (err, rows) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Problem with MySQL" + err);
        }
        else {
            res.end(JSON.stringify(rows));
        }
    });
});

app.get('/addToHistory', function (req, res) {
    //THIS METHOD IS RECALLING EVERY 2 MINUTES
    console.log('addToHistory');
    var imageID = req.query.imageID;
    var sessionID = req.cookies['image-session'];
    sessionID = sessionID.substring(sessionID.indexOf(':') + 1, sessionID.indexOf('.'));
    checkIfExist();

    function checkIfExist(){
        db_connection.query('SELECT * FROM `history` WHERE `session_id`="'+sessionID+'" AND `image_id`="'+imageID+'"', function (error, rows) {
            if (error) {
                console.log('Problem with MySQL' + error);
            }else{
                if(rows.length >= 1){
                    updateExisting();
                }else{
                    createNew();
                }
            }
        })
    }

    function createNew() {
        db_connection.query('INSERT INTO `history` (`session_id`, `image_id`) VALUES ("' + sessionID + '", "' + imageID + '")', function (error, rows) {
            if (error) {
                console.log('Problem with MySQL' + error);
            }else{

            }
        })
    }

    function updateExisting(){
        db_connection.query('UPDATE history SET created=NOW() WHERE `session_id`="'+sessionID+'" AND `image_id`="'+imageID+'"', function(error, rows){
            if (error) {
                console.log('Problem with MySQL' + error);
            }else{

            }
        })
    }

});

var connection = mysql.createConnection(db_options);
var sessionStore = new MySQLStore(option, connection);

app.use(session({
    name: 'image-session',
    secret: 'thisidasnkjcmsxhodsjafasd89fdashojnva',
    cookie: {maxAge: 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, httpOnly: false, secure: false},
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: sessionStore
}));

app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/app/js'));
app.use('/bower_components', express.static(__dirname + '/app/bower_components'));
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/app/css'));
app.use('/partials', express.static(__dirname + '/app/partials'));
app.use('/views', express.static(__dirname + '/app/views'));
app.use('/components', express.static(__dirname + '/app/components'));
app.use('/images', express.static(__dirname + '/app/images'));

app.use(function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.session.id)
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/app/index.html')
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, function () {
    console.log("Server is listening ");
});
```

When user click on some of the images it is opening a new page (state) with a controller which is calling a factory function. Here is my factory:

```
app.factory('dbCommunication', ['$http', function ($http) {

    var obj = {};

    obj.addToHistory = function(image){
        console.log('call');
        $http.get('http://localhost:8080/addToHistory?imageID='+image.id).success(function(data){
        })

        return;
    }

    return obj;

}]);
```

Any idea why node.js is reloading **app.get('/addToHistory'** every 2 minutes?

BTW. I would like to ask what do you think about my server.js configuration. Is it OK? Should I change something in it? I am not sure if it is a good idea do keep SessionID into cookie.

Comment: I really suspect this is in your angular code...  I would attempt to simplify all aspects of  your application (e.g. remove DB, reduce the number of UI elements) and add them back to see where the problem is introduced.

Comment: When I am opening the page I am seeing console.log('call') in browser and then I am seeing console.log('addToHistory'); from nodeJS. After every next reload I am seeing only node js console.log. That's why I thing that problem is in node.js not in Angular.

Comment: I don'tsee anything with the res object in the addToHistory method...  I dont know if that would cause  your problem though...   But maybe try res.end() in there...

Comment: res.end() resolve the problem